# Macro to enter user name and password directly on a website

Tags: macros

Well, I'm using Google Chrome as my web browser and for some reason I can't save my username and password for my university portal account. So, each time I log in I have to enter it again. It's not that tiring I know, but I was wondering if there is some kind of program to execute so as it automatically fills the username field with my username and  field with my password. I hope it's clear.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program such as [Kee Pass](http://keepass.info/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off with a keystore like [Gnome Key Ring](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/).

Answer (score 0):

Sicen you are using Chrome, here is a [plugin](http://www.passter.com/) specifically for Chrome, to then be run inside the browser.